# AR model disappear at some distance though I set AR camera far clipping plane to 5000

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I need help with one project based on the AR + GPS.
I have to place the model at GPS location at runtime and the player has to find that model.

I completed almost part of the project using assets AR + GPS Location to place the model at lat-long. I also use one asset named TriLib 2 - Model Loading Package to load the model from the URL.

I am facing one issue **with some android devices.**
The model does not appear at some distance(i.e 20 meters away) and if I am inside the range of the 20 meters then it appears on the screen.
**I set the AR camera far clipping to 5000.**

On iOS devices, it works perfectly fine. On some android devices, it also works fine.
What will be the issue?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IDhH3SrzVFg

Please see the video(time: 3.08) for reference.

On Real Me XT, iPhone X it is working.

On Samsung Galaxy S10 and Xiaomi Redmi Note 9 Pro, The model is disappearing at some distance.